# LTspice: when I turn a schematic into a subcircuit it behaves differently. Why?

Tags: simulation, spice, ltspice

I'm trying to model a low frequency LED flasher based on a [BEAM Pummer](http://www.beam-wiki.org/wiki/BEP_Pummer) (basically a pair of CMOS inverters wired as an oscillator, plus a charge pump) in LTspice. I have the base flasher circuit attached to a voltage source and LED output, and it seems to be working correctly, producing ~40mA current spikes through the LED every ~2s or so.

But when I try to make a .subckt definition with the flasher part only, and include that in a test circuit, it doesn't work correctly: I get a noisy µA-level output through the led wired to the output pins for a few ns, then the oscillator locks up.

- The SPICE error log reports `Singular matrix: Check node d:u1:6#int1 Iteration No. 19` which doesn't show up with the standalone version. I'm not sure how to find node `d:u1:6#int1`.
- My initial guess was that a `GND` connection wasn't being made properly, but I tried to pass a ground reference through an external pin several different ways and it didn't made any difference.
- There's a quirk in that I need to use a `PULSE` voltage supply with 100% duty cycle rather than a steady DC voltage in the standalone version, or the oscillator won't start. Could this be related? Setting the test circuit's voltage to `PULSE` didn't seem to make any difference.

What else might I be doing wrong? I've triple checked the .subckt netlist pin order against the order defined in the symbol file, and I'm pretty sure it's correct. The docs tell me that `GND` should already be globally connected. Is it a startup thing? Two inverters are wired in a chain to make the oscillator, do I need to explicitly set the input of one to 5V and the other to 0V at startup?

For reference, there's a zip file [here](http://frey.co.nz/content/stuff/ltspice_subcircuit_weirdness.zip) containing the test schematic and the .sub and .asy definitions, as well as the standalone version of the flasher subcircuit to prove that it does actually work.

Any help greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To answer my own question: it seems LTspice requires text files to be saved with Windows Latin 1 code page, CRLF line endings. I'm using Wine on a Mac, and my text-editor saves as UTF-8 by default. I'm guessing LTspice misinterprets the UTF-8 µ on capacitor values as something invalid, but confusingly doesn't throw an error message.

Comment: Considering that SPICE is a (quite old) computer language, replacing of u with µ causing problems is probably not too surprising.

Comment: LTSpice is picky about units. For instance, if you want to use megohms, you have to spell the units just right, otherwise it silently substitutes another resistance that is orders of magnitude off.  It doesn't accept M, just Meg with a capital M.

Comment: No, @Kaz, you are not correct. In no case LTspice "silently substitutes" a resistance! If a valid suffix is used (M, m, Meg, MEG, etc. are all valid), then there is no need for LTspice "to complain", otherwise it will, of course. SPICEs, incl. LTspice, are CASE INSENSITIVE, so any "uppercase/lowercase combination" of MEG (mEg, MeG,...) is interpreted as 'mega' (x 1e6), both 'M' and 'm' as 'milli' (x 0.001). Since the subsequent characters are ignored by SPICEs, units can also be entered, for inst. 4.7uF (that 'F' has no effect). Pay, however, attention: 0.001F = 0.001femtoFarad not 0.001Farad!

Comment: @EricBest This is a bug because in electronics shorthand we distinguish `M` and `m`. If I see 2M next to a resistor on a schematic, that to me means two million ohms, not two milliohms. It's fine to treat Meg, MEG and meg as equivalent, but not M and m.

Comment: @Kaz, it's not a bug, it is simply a consequence of the fact that SPICEs are (historically) CASE INSENSITIVE. That's why a "compromise" had to be chosen to distinguish these common well known shorthands for "milli"(m) and "mega"(M). One must simply reconcile with it...

Comment: @EricBest: Ever accidentally wrote 10mig or 10mug or 10mfg or similar for a resistor value? It will be interpreted as 10 milli. This *is* a usability bug, unless you say that error reporting is not needed and whenever you get something wrong in your .asc file nasal demons are a proper consequence.

Comment: @PlasmaHH: No. Bug is an error made during programming, something that originated unintentionally. This is NOT the case. The basic functionality of SPICEs is that they INTENTIONALLY recognize(parse) just the !first! letter placed IMMEDIATELY behind the value (other arbitrary letters can follow it without any effect) unless these letters create the word MEG (or its upper/lower case combinations) in which case it is evaluated as the prefix 'mega'. Only if that 1st letter isn't identical with one of the expected prefixes or it is not the 'meg case' described above it gives an error message.

Comment: @EricBest: A bug is also an error in the specification that later turns out to be not really what you wanted and/or is useful. When a calculator outputs 3 for 1+1 then it is a bug, regardless of the spec saying so.

Comment: @PlasmaHH: No. Once more: The described behaviour is fully INTENDED from the very beginning. Your comparison example is wrong - it is not analogical. If a calculator outputs 3 for 1+1, it's a bug, no doubt. The input values were entered in a right way and the expected result is wrong. In our case if the input is ok (according to the given spec), then the result will be ok as well. You can't expect a right result if you have entered a nonsense as an input. (cont.)

Comment: @PlasmaHH:  (cont.) The specification is clear: whatever beginning with 'm' or 'M'(the price for the inherent case insensitivity) is entered, it always means "milli" unless it continues 'eg...', 'Eg...', 'eG...' or 'EG...', then it means "mega". This property allows to insert units like mV, mVolt, mA, milliamps, mH, milliHenry, etc., as all the subsequent letters are ignored.

Comment: OMG the penis waving here as astonishing.

Comment: @PlasmaHH +1 'nasal demons'